# Can I resell diesel to a trucking company's fleet during a price hike?

Tags: united-states, california, licensing, finance

Say I have a container of diesel which I purchased at a low rate and got a discount for a bulk purchase. Can I resell it to a trucking company's fleet of truckers at a competitive rate in a high-price diesel market, legally?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why not.  After all, this is the entire point of commodity futures.  Note that diesel does have a finite storage life (sources I saw suggest 6-12 months or perhaps more depending on conditions) so you can't wait forever.  It's also possible that the trucking company may have rules about where they can get their fuel, in order to be sure of its quality.

Comment: OK, so there isn't a licensing/permit issue with selling? It is a hazardous material.

Comment: Oh, I see.  That's possible.